# Unable to insert record through jquery ajax without refreshing page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a regular form.
On inserting record i don't want the page to refresh.

i m using ajax jquery mysqli for this.

```
$('#myform').submit(function(){
    return false;
});


$('#insert').click(function(){
    var form = $('#myform').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url:"insert.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:form,
        success:function(data){
            $('#result').html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

If i remove

```
$('#myform').submit(function(){
    return false;
});
```

then form inserts record but not with this. what can be done?

insert.php file:

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/con1_i.php'); ?>
<?php 
    $CartProductID = $_POST['ProductID'];
    $CartProductSellingPrice = $_POST['ProductSellingPrice'];
    $CartProductQty = $_POST['ProductQuantity'];
    $CartProductTax = $_POST['ProductTax']; 
    $CartUserID = $_POST['UserID']; 
    $CartSessionID = $_POST['SessionID'];       
    $sql = "insert into Carts (CartProductID, CartProductSellingPrice, CartProductQty, CartProductTax, CartUserID, CartSessionID) values ('$CartProductID','$CartProductSellingPrice', '$CartProductQty', '$CartProductTax', '$CartUserID', '$CartSessionID')";

    if(mysqli_query($con1_i, $sql)){
        echo 'success';
    }
?>
```

Comment: is `insert` a button or input/submit?

Comment: #insert is a button ID

Comment: Need some basic debugging done. Is request being made and is it succeeding?  If so what are you receiving in `$_POST`? If not is click event firing? You really haven't given us much in the way of clues to work with. You can also inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network to verify what is being sent, status, response body etc

Comment: @charlietfl i m not sure about this. everything fine on insert.php record page.  `$('#myform').submit(function(){
    return false;
});` if i remove this line, record does insert.

Comment: on removing that line, the page goes to action page & inserts record. i dont need the page to refresh.

Comment: You just said the same thing twice. Anyway... have you tried just removing the 'success' callback?

Comment: Replace your success function with:`success:function(data){
            $('#result').html(data);
        }`

Comment: this question is getting little complicated, cos i had to add another button is same form. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57944480/insert-mysqli-record-without-refreshing-page-multiple-buttons

Answer (score 0):

Undefined variable `result`

You did not used `data` in `success:` function:

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $('#myform').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url:"insert.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:form,
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I think all are working fine & you missed just *success* message